# Date parse issue WebApi Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Returning a POCO with a DateTime field from Asp.net WebApi to an Angular2 front end results in null values being transformed in the `res.json()`method. Obviously, I could return strings here, and parse to and from, but that feels like a hack.

Is there a standard way around this. I've omitted the WebApi code as it just returns a POCO with a DateTime property.

Here is the Angular2 code:

```
  getRequestById(id: number): Observable<RequestViewModel> {
        return this._http.get(this.requestUrl + '/' + id).map((res: Response) => {
              let result = res.json();
              console.log('serialized json ', result); //here the fromDate is null
              console.log('actual response', res); // here the _body.fromDate has a value of '5/11/2017 1:51:45 AM';
              return result;
        });
  }
```

Is there an accepted way to deal with DateTime -> Typescript Date? Is it possible to access the _body property to parse the result myself?

Many thanks in advance,

KH

Comment: In general, Dates can be pretty bad to work with on the client side (javascript).  You'd be better off working with strings.  If you have to manipulate dates, use `moment.js` to cast between strings and dates, do offsets, etc.  Just be aware that a lot can go wrong with time zone issues between the client and the server.

Comment: This is what I feared! I was hoping there was a standard solution. I guess I could parse all dates as strings to UTC. Thanks

Comment: I disagree with the above conclusion. I have never had any issues or needed to do any custom date parsing in my angular webapi apps. Something is not right. Can you post the result json?

Comment: you mean the Typescript definition or the parsed json? - the parsed json is fine, except the dates, which are null.